# How to access a value from a class with initializers without passing in the arguments needed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class called pagdataSource with an initializer: 
        class PagDataSource {

```
         var itemsOffSet: Int
           /////some other variables

init(messages: [Message], itemGenerator: ((Int) -> TextModel)? ) {
       //////initializing
}
```

The point is, I need to access itemsOffset from another class. Here's how i tried doing so.

```
  class randomClass {


   var offset = PagDataSource().itemsOffSet     
       //gives error, arguments required. 
 }
```

Is there a way to access the itemsOffset variable without passing in variables for initialization?

Comment: try using `static var itemsOffSet: Int`

Comment: why would you want to access a variable of a class without initialising it? Of what use is that value? You probably should pass the correct instance of `PagDataSource` around your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write `var offset = PagDataSource().itemsOffSet` in the `randomClass` you need to add a convenience initialiser to your `PagDataSource` class:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(messages: [],itemGenerator: nil)
}
```

Comment: awesome, totally forgot about convenience initializers. It worked fine simply with  convenience init() {
    self.init()
}, however thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

PagDataSource init takes two arguments messages and itemGenerator. but you are passing nothing while creating the object. either create the paramaterized init or create one more init with no parameter.

for example:

class PagDataSource {

```
     var itemsOffSet: Int

init(messages: [Message], itemGenerator: ((Int) -> TextModel)? ) {
   //////initializing
 }

init() {
 ...
 }
}
```

and access it like

```
let pagDataSource = PagDataSource()
var offset = pagDataSource.offset
```